# UTF-8 pages appear as garbage

Tags: windows-7, email, browser, utf-8

On many occasions, when my browser (either Explorer or Chrome) on my Windows 7 Pro machine hit a UTF-8 page, what I get is garbage that looks like this one: http://24.media.tumblr.com/7865bc12fc4430c4e3678473761717cf/tumblr_mnrhvhGM5O1qfjuqlo1_500.jpg

(One may see the REAL thing here: http://www.hexagon.com/en/index.htm).

OK...What's wrong here?!

And mind you—this annoying issue affects also MS Outlook messages, so it seems I'm having a system-deep issue rather than browser or specific site fault...

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your font settings need to be reset:

1. Start Search "Fonts".
2. In the left pane, click Font settings.
3. Click Restore default font settings.

Source: [Link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26)

Or try deleting your font cache:

`C:\Windows\System32\fntcache.dat`

Source: [Link](http://www.ehow.com/how_7197467_rebuild-font-cache.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, Harreh! Tried both suggested, and peculiarly enough—some items look better, some are still same garbage...see http://25.media.tumblr.com/fc13c2daa73d2742162aa7d9d5e70b29/tumblr_mnrppwoxgD1qfjuqlo1_500.jpg (highlighted parts are still gibberish, titles look fine now...). Any further advice will be extremely nice of anyone!

Comment: It's possible that the font files themselves are damaged/corrupted.

Comment: Not likely; everything else is working just fine. But if I doubt it—what would you recommend me doing to verify this is not the cause (or exactly is)?

Comment: Good point, you could be right. It sounds like a browser issue (assuming Outlook essentially displays messages via IE). Chrome and Firefox both have encoding settings (Under 'Content'). For IE 10, rightclick the page and select 'Encoding'.

Comment: Oh...I drilled THAT so many times...! Nothing helped. I practically tried ANY Encoding option, to no avail. The only thing that helps (and may hint on a solution I am not aware of) is to go into Explorer's Tools-->General-->Accessibility, and there—Ignore font styles specified on webpages. This, however, affects other display "things" (and has no effect on Chrome on same machine)...